# Can't install libnotify-dev due to version blocked dependencies

Tags: apt, 18.04, aptitude, libnotify

Step #1 ...

```
sudo apt-get -y update;
sudo apt-get -y upgrade;
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade;
sudo apt-get -y clean;
sudo apt-get -y autoremove;
```

... results in ...

```
Hit:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                             
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                      
Hit:7 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Step #2 ...

```
sudo apt install libnotify-dev
```

... results in ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnotify-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.26) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Step #3 ...

```
sudo aptitude install libnotify-dev
```

... results in ...

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-8-base:i386{ab} libblkid1:i386{ab} libc6:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{ab} libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev{a} 
  libglib2.0-0:i386{ab} libglib2.0-bin:i386{ab} libglib2.0-dev{ab} libglib2.0-dev-bin{a} libmount1:i386{ab} libnotify-dev libpcre16-3{a} 
  libpcre3:i386{a} libpcre3-dev{a} libpcre32-3{a} libpcrecpp0v5{a} libpng-dev{a} libpng-tools{a} libpthread-stubs0-dev{a} libselinux1:i386{a} 
  libuuid1:i386{ab} libx11-dev{ab} libx11-doc{a} libxau-dev{a} libxcb1-dev{a} libxdmcp-dev{a} pkg-config{a} x11proto-core-dev{a} x11proto-dev{a} 
  xorg-sgml-doctools{a} xtrans-dev{a} zlib1g:i386{a} zlib1g-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 35 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 48.7 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmount1 : Breaks: libmount1:i386 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libmount1:i386 : Breaks: libmount1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 gcc-8-base : Breaks: gcc-8-base:i386 (!= 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04) but 8-20180414-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 gcc-8-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-8-base (!= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
 libgcc1 : Breaks: libgcc1:i386 (!= 1:8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04) but 1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc1 (!= 1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 1:8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
 libblkid1 : Breaks: libblkid1:i386 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libblkid1:i386 : Breaks: libblkid1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Conflicts: libglib2.0-bin:i386 but 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-bin:i386 : Conflicts: libglib2.0-bin but 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
 libx11-dev : Depends: libx11-6 (= 2:1.6.4-3) but 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
open: 44; closed: 1251; defer: 26; conflict: 34                                                                                                        

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      gcc-8-base:i386 [Not Installed]                    
2)      libblkid1:i386 [Not Installed]                     
3)      libc6:i386 [Not Installed]                         
4)      libelf1:i386 [Not Installed]                       
5)      libffi6:i386 [Not Installed]                       
6)      libgcc1:i386 [Not Installed]                       
7)      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev [Not Installed]               
8)      libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                  
9)      libglib2.0-bin:i386 [Not Installed]                
10)     libglib2.0-dev [Not Installed]                     
11)     libmount1:i386 [Not Installed]                     
12)     libnotify-dev [Not Installed]                      
13)     libpcre3:i386 [Not Installed]                      
14)     libselinux1:i386 [Not Installed]                   
15)     libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]                      
16)     libx11-dev [Not Installed]                         
17)     zlib1g:i386 [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

... but accepting merely gets me ...

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Versions:

```
lsb_release -a
```

... shows ...

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

How can I resolve this and get the package to install?

**Update 2019-03-28 18:05 EST**

Also tried ...

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
```

... getting ...

```
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev : Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev :       Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1)
```

**Update 2019-03-29 06:45 EST**

Per the question by @fkraiem:

```
apt-cache policy libglib2.0-dev
```

... produces ...

```
libglib2.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.56.1-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.56.1-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirror.clibre.uqam.ca/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Per the concern expressed by @Mamayogi:

```
dpkg --print-architecture; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures;
```

... produces ...

```
amd64
i386
```

... but, nevertheless, the command `sudo apt install libnotify-dev` gives the same 'unmet dependencies' result as at first.

Comment: What about `sudo apt install libnotify-dev libglib2.0-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`?

Comment: @fkraiem, thanks for the suggestion, but it's not the answer.   I updated the question.

Comment: Of course it's not "the answer", that's why it's a comment... Your `libglib2.0-dev` looks funny. What does `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-dev` say?

Comment: It seems that you have not enabled `Multi-arch support`. Issue this command:`dpkg --print-architecture`, the output should be:`amd64`. Issue second command:`dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, the output should be:`i386`. It is so, then you are good! Other wise, give the sequence of commands:1)  `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, 2) `sudo apt-get update` and 3) `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Finally issue the command: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and see the output is `i386`. Now you have enabled `Multi-arch support` successfully! Now go for:  `sudo apt install libnotify-dev`

Comment: @fkraiem, thanks for sticking with this.  I show the results of the policy check in the second update. Would the **500** mean that `uqam.ca` has a server error?

Comment: @Marmayogi thank you for your detailed comment.  I show the results in the second update.

Comment: Your ubuntu system has Multi-arch support enabled already. But why should `sudo aptitude install libnotify-dev` complain about so many missing 32-libraries? @Martin Bramwell, why don't you re-install i386 (i.e, 32-bit libraries)? The command sequence is already given in my previous comment. There is nothing harmful in attempting again. So please try!

Comment: The latest version of `libglib2.0-dev` in Bionic is `2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`, but your system does not see it. It could be because the [mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) you are using is out of date; try [using another one](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/how-to-change-ubuntu-repository-mirror-sources.html?m=1).

Comment: @MartinBramwell the 500 means the priority. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121413/understanding-the-output-of-apt-cache-policy (To your situation: I think you've got a lot of 3rd party sources, but where are the original ubuntu sources? There should be at least 2 lines in `apt-cache policy`.)

Comment: @Marmayogi, so I just tried that (adding arch then updating), but it did not seem to change anything.  I do not think it is a question of missing libraries so much as of conflicting libraries. Each one, says 'pkgX breaks pkgX:i386' and then immediately 'pkgX:i386 breaks pkgX'

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-dev` on my desktop is: `libglib2.0-dev:  Installed: 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1  Candidate: 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1,   Version table: *** 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500 ......`. I have perfect installation of both 64-bit (amd64) and 32-bit libraries (i386). I  suspect that you  have incomplete or broken i386 installation. Unless you rectify this, it is hard to install `libglib2.0-dev`. Remember @MartinBramwell, it will not take more than a  minute to install `libglib2.0-dev` if your system is clean and perfect.

Comment: @fkraiem.  You seem to have the right idea.  I switched mirrors and ran `apt update; apt upgrade; apt dist-upgrade;` 10 minutes ago and it is still churning away at all the alterations. Hope I can reboot after all that. :-(

Comment: @fkraiem, so yes, your last comment turns out actually to be the answer this time.  Very grateful! Thanks.  It had not previously occurred to me that some mirror servers would be substandard.  Is there no QA monitoring?  How does one report this?

Comment: There is some sort of monitoring, on the page I linked above you have the time of the last known update of the mirror (and for the one you used it was actually unknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause of unavailable dependencies, especially when the desired package is an official one, is an out-of-date archive mirror, as was the case here. One can see a list of all available archive mirrors and their update status [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors); if your mirror is out of date, try another one.